# ¿Cómo saber si un registro existe en una tabla de Sql (dentro de una consulta)?

Tags: c#, sql

He investigado diferentes formas de saber si un registro existe dentro una tabla en SQL, pero la mayoría me lo marca dentro de un procedimiento almacenado, y yo quisiera saber la forma de hacerlo por dentro de una simple consulta para que después de realizar la consulta me de un valor para poder compara si existe o no un registro. Si existe pues asigno un 1 a mi variable y sino asigno un 0 a mi variable y dicha variable hara el resto del recorrido.

Código actual:

```
SELECT 
    rfc
FROM tEmpresa
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT rfc
        FROM tEmpresa
        WHERE rfc = 'DMC750410C41'
        );
```

Actualmente estoy trabajando sobre código de C#, y el código que puse en la parte de arriba no me funciona de la mejor manera, ya que me trae todos los registros.

Imagen de el resultado de la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedes hacer `select rfc from tEmpresa where rfc='DMC750410C41'` y luego algun tipo de `Count` de registros?  si `count>0` entonces existe no ?

Comment: @lois6b tambien es viable, creo que seria una buena opcion. aunque seguiria sin saber porque me marca erronea la consulta, pero gracias por tu aporte vere la forma de hacer lo que comentas.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que intentas. Si es saber si un registros con rfc=x existe, simplemente `select count(*) from tEmpresa where rfc='DMC750410C41'` no te sirve? si devuelve 0,el registro no existe

Comment: Adicionalmente el resultado de la consulta es correcto ya que la condicion es que exista un registro con tal rfc para mostar el select el cual seleccionara todos los registros, falta una condicion adicional para filtrar solamente el registro solicitado por lo que la sugerencia de @Pikoh simplifica la consulta a no ser que quieras devolver otra cosa si es que el registro no existe

Comment: Hola @David, una pregunta, ¿estás utilizando SQL Server o cuál es el manejador de base de datos que usas?

Answer (score 1):

por lo que entiendo necesitas una consulta que regrese 1 ó 0 para determinar verdadero o falso

podrías hacer lo siguiente

```
SELECT 
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tEmpresa WHERE rfc = 'DMC750410C41' = 0 ) > 0, true, false
FROM tEmpresa
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu base de datos es **MS SQL** puedes intentar un **CASE**

```
SELECT 
CASE rfc
    WHEN 'DMC750410C41'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
    AS Existe
FROM
    tEmpresa 
WHERE
    rfc='DMC750410C41'
```

**Nota:** Esta implementacion no es a prueba de registros duplicados.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT top 1 1 FROM tEmpresa WHERE rfc='DMC750410C41'),0)
```